# saving aspx page into an image

Tags: c#, asp.net

need to convert, an aspx page with a panel having image and some labels into it, as an image

in details i would say i need to save the image some text content on it as a new image...

please help soon running out of target...

Comment: So you basically want to convert the whole ASP page, controls, text, images, etc. into one big image and have the user download it? I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 4):

Write a winforms app with a WebBrowser control in it. Tell the WebBrowser to load the url, wait for it to finish and then use [this](http://blog.tcx.be/2004/12/painting-control-onto-graphics-object.html) to paint your form into a bitmap. Use BitMap.Save to save the final image.

Answer (score -1):

Just make a screenshot. Either by printscrn or by code.